# Change image with arrow key?

Tags: javascript

I have an image that is moved around the screen with the arrow keys. I would like to know how to change the image being moved with each key.

I realize that the image is attached to each movement. The movements are not attached to each image.

Here is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function leftArrowPressed() {var element = document.getElementById("image1");
element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 10 + 'px';}

function rightArrowPressed() {var element = document.getElementById("image1");
element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 10 + 'px';}

function upArrowPressed() {var element = document.getElementById("image1");
element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 10 + 'px';}

function downArrowPressed() {var element = document.getElementById("image1");
element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 10 + 'px';}


function moveSelection(event) {                    
switch (event.keyCode) {
case 37:leftArrowPressed();break;
case 39:rightArrowPressed();break;
case 38:upArrowPressed();break;
case 40:downArrowPressed();break;
}
};


function gameLoop()
{
// change position based on speed
moveSelection();
setTimeout("gameLoop()",10);
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="gameLoop();" onkeydown="moveSelection(event)" onkeyup="moveSelection(event)"'>

<img id="image1" src="images/casual.png" style="position: absolute; left: 15; right: 15; top: 15; bottom: auto; " height="20" width="16">
</body>
```

Comment: Do you mean just changing it's source: `element.src = "newImage.png"`? If so just do that in each `ArrowPressed()` function.

Comment: I tried this in the way that V31 said, but although my images now change, they no longer move.

Comment: Because the answer removed that functionality, simply do what I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: I tried this as function downArrowPressed() {var element = document.getElementById("image1").src = "images/casual.png";
element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 10 + 'px';}  The image stops moving all the same. I am new to javascript so I may be doing this wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of your `ArrowPressed()` functions simply change the `src` of the element to what you want for each arrow key:

```
function downArrowPressed() {
    var element = document.getElementById("image1");
    element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 10 + 'px';
    element.src = "imageForDownArrow.png";
}

function upArrowPressed() {
    var element = document.getElementById("image1");
    element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 10 + 'px';
    element.src = "imageForUpArrow.png";
}

function leftArrowPressed() {
    var element = document.getElementById("image1");
    element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 10 + 'px';
    element.src = "imageForLeftArrow.png";
}

function rightArrowPressed() {
    var element = document.getElementById("image1");
    element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
    element.src = "imageForRightArrow.png";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the src property of the img tag on key press. Created a small [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sx3fuL6b/) to demonstrate the same.

Code:

```
function changeImage() {
    document.getElementById("image1").src = "http://andrefrommalta.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/137392976177.jpg";
}

function changeImage2() {
    document.getElementById("image1").src = "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_IY7CmWJmPL4/R8K5bFaKXpI/AAAAAAAABO0/fH7E6kPibuM/S1600-R/random.jpg";
}

function changeImage3() {
    document.getElementById("image1").src = "http://www.newton.ac.uk/files/covers/968361.jpg";
}

function changeImage4() {
    document.getElementById("image1").src = "http://k41.kn3.net/taringa/1/7/0/5/5/4/74/gatessb/E6F.gif?3362";
}

function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        //up arrow
        changeImage();
    } else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        // down arrow
        changeImage2();
    } else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        // left arrow
        changeImage3();
    } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        // right arrow
        changeImage4();
    }

}

document.onkeydown = checkKey;
```

Comment: The image does not move though now.